# Retrieving a value from an empty interface

Tags: json, encoding, go

I have an empty interface to which I have parsed some *json* data.

```
type Event interface {
}
```

As of now, the only value is `name`, and this is being set correctly. However, I cannot figure how to actually retrieve the value of this variable. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

If you did something this to unmarshel the json

```
var f interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &f)
```

You can use a type assertion to access `f`'s underlying map[string]interface{}:

```
m := f.(map[string]interface{})
```

For more detail read [this](http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go) blog post.

Try It on  <kbd>[Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/Y9a5rvnRxJ)</kbd>